# Writing a simple applet in linux

Tags: linux, shell, applet, gnome

I want to write a simple applet to put in a tray. Let's say it will be for gnome taskbar or tint2. My applet should show system temperature or any other simple information by probing at a fixed amount of time /proc or maybe providing this info by clicking on the applet itself, I still have not decided.

My knowledge is limited, since I don't know where to start. What I need is some little info, on the difficulty of the matter, provided I'm fairly ok with bash, but that's it.
Where do I start and what should I read first? There should be gui, then is it gtk, qt or something else? Maybe somebody got a good link or just your opinion will be a good start for me.

Comment: What programming languages are you familiar with?

Comment: as I mentioned not much: Bash, awk mostly. I want to learn python however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean GNOME 2, you could start reading the document [Gnome applets with Python](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/applets_arturogf/).  You will get the idea behind applets and how to do it with Python.  For tin2 the API might be totally different.